# Dynamic Multiple NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have this scenario that I'll perform a query in SQLite and I need to declare a multiple array based on the number of groups so basically my problem is:

**1.) How to declare multiple array**

**e.g**

```
NSMutableArray *first = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *second = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *third= [NSMutableArray new];
```

I need to do that in a dynamic way like

```
NSMutableArray *dynamic = based on groupCount
```

**Query sample:**

```
SELECT groupNumber, name FROM sample


if(groupNumber == 0){
[first addObject:name];
}
else if(groupNumber == 1){
[second addObject:name];
}
```

Comment: You can put an `NSMutableArray` inside another.

Comment: Use a `NDictionary`, have the key be the `groupNumber` and the value a `NSMutableArray` of the `name`s.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two-dimensional NSMutableArray of mutable arrays, but don't know how many I'll need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775343/two-dimensional-nsmutablearray-of-mutable-arrays-but-dont-know-how-many-ill-n)

Comment: is it possible to Add an object of NSMutableArray inside the NSDcitionary based on its key?

Comment: Yeah, you'd get the array out for that key and then add an item to it.

Comment: @RonPelayo I'd post an example put you haven't really give much code that you have at the moment. Does the result of the query come back as an `NSArray` or...?

Comment: Nope it comes back as a NSString so it's 2 NSString because row1 is groupnumber and row2 is name

Comment: @RonPelayo but what about each row in the query - what format does the data set come back in?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, really, but the obvious thing [to me, at least] would to be to use an array containing n arrays, then you can pull the one you want out by its index:

```
NSMutableArray *bigArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

...

```
if (groupNumber < [bigArray count])
{
    NSMutableArray *workArray = [bigArray objectAtIndex:groupNumber];
    [workArray addObject:name];
}
else
{
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [newArray addObject:name];
    [bigArray addObject:newArray];
}
```

Not sure if that code works but maybe it will give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment - use a `NDictionary`, have the key be the `groupNumber` and the value a `NSMutableArray` of the `name`s.

First create your dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *groups = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Then in your loop:

```
NSMutableArray *group = groups[groupNumber];
if (!group) {
    group = [NSMutableArray array];
    groups[groupNumber] = group;
}
[group addObject:name];
```

Now `groups` would look like:

```
{
    "1" : ["name1", "name2", "name3"],
    "3" : ["name4", "name6"]
}
```